# Insert Property of Picture Class

Tags: image, vba, excel

I have read all of the questions on here about this topic and none of them provided me with a workable solution, so I'm asking this one.

I am running a legitimate copy of Excel 2013 in Windows 7. I record a macros where I insert a picture, and in the open file dialog I paste this URL: `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41u%2BilIi00L._SL160_.jpg` (simply a picture of a product on Amazon). This works as expected.

The resulting macros looks like this:

```
Sub insertImage()
'
' percent Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert( _
        "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41u+ilIi00L._SL160_.jpg").Select
End Sub
```

However, when I attempt to run this, the `Insert` line breaks with the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004':

Unable to get the Insert property of the Picture class
```

I am trying to insert a number of pictures into an excel document and I am using the `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert` method to do this. I have been experiencing this issue there, so I recreated it in a way others could replicate to facilitate getting an answer...

An interesting thing to note is:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41u%2BilIi00L._SL160_.jpg 'This is what I pasted
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41u+ilIi00L._SL160_.jpg 'This is what the recorded macros recorded
```

It looks like Excel automatically resolved the `%2B` to a `+`. I tried making that change, but to no success.

Another interesting thing to note is that sometimes this does work and sometimes it doesn't. This url is a case where it does not work. Here's one where it does: `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51mXQ-IjigL._SL160_.jpg`

Why would Excel generate a macros it can't run? More importantly, how can I avoid this error and get on with my work!? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this workaround:

```
Sub RetrieveImage()
Dim wsht As Worksheet: Set wsht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
wsht.Shapes.AddPicture "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41u+ilIi00L._SL160_.jpg", _
                    msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 100, 100
End Sub
```

All fields are required, which is kind of a bummer since you cannot get the default size. The location offsets and sizes are in pixels/points. Also, the `%` turning to `+` is just alright, as `%` would cause it to be not recognized (dunno why).

Result:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Curious... I copy and pasted your code exactly and it gave me a run-time error: "The specified file wasn't found." on the `AddPicture` line.

Comment: Are you using `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51mXQ-IjigL._SL160_.jpg`? Don't use that one, use the original one recorded from your macro.

Comment: Curious and curious-er, dear Watson. What if you use the URL working for you? Because on my end, your working URL is throwing the `specified file...` error.

Comment: Someone at Microsoft is just trolling us or something because when I use: `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51mXQ-IjigL._SL160_.jpg` it works fine, but when I use `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41u+ilIi00L._SL160_.jpg` it breaks...

Comment: Won't be surprised with the troll. Excel 2013 and Windows 8 are perfect examples of trolling anyway. ;) Hope this helped, even if it's not a perfect answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm experiencing the same issue.
After some digging I found out Excel does a HTTP HEAD request before getting the image.
If this HEAD request is unsuccessful Excel will return the exact error messages mentioned in this discussion.

Your could easily test this using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).