Is there a way to create a macro that converts these hyperlinks into embedded images in Excel?
I frequently generate spreadsheets of multiple rows of images. Before our database switched platforms, I was able to use a macro that converted the hyperlinks into embedded images. However, since switching platforms, the hyperlinks are generated differently, and the macro no longer works.
This is the original macro we would use:
Sub URLPictureInsert()
    Dim theShape As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J2:J10")
    For Each cell In rng
        Filename = cell
        Set theShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
            Filename:=Filename, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
            Left:=cell.Left, Top:=cell.Top, Width:=60, Height:=60)
        If theShape Is Nothing Then GoTo isnill
        With theShape
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Top = cell.Top + 1
            .Left = cell.Left + 1
            .Height = cell.Height - 2
            .Width = cell.Width - 2
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        ' Get rid of the
        cell.ClearContents
isnill:
        Set theShape = Nothing
        Range("A2").Select

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Done " & Now

End Sub

These are how the hyperlinks used to be generated:



Animal Photo




httpsa//www.shelterluv.com/sites/default/files/animal_pics/18283/2024/10/05/09/20241005093116.png


https://www.shelterluv.com/sites/default/files/animal_pics/18283/2024/10/17/11/20241017114413.png


https://www.shelterluv.com/sites/default/files/animal_pics/18283/2024/10/18/16/20241018163656.png



These are how the hyperlinks are generated now, to where the macro doesn't work:



Animal Photo




https://sl-v2-prod.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/profile-pictures/2e60d1118c35ca2072583c8757e270d5/8bb5679c4913dfeeab2587cab85fe199.jpg


https://sl-v2-prod.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/profile-pictures/e6663723d3c1bd8ea9f2e961270659de/20241106165702.png


https://sl-v2-prod.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/profile-pictures/5dcc1cdbd850cbe22283ce75d597dcff/20241106181308.png




If you comment out the On Error Resume Next then what happens with the new URL format?

There seems to be a problem with Excel downloading images from Amazon S3 buckets - see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415934/insert-property-of-picture-class/32502926#32502926   You can get round this by first downloading the image to your Temp folder, and inserting the image from there.

The issue is described in the link I posted in my comment above -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32502926/478884

I'm experiencing the same issue. After some digging I found out Excel
does a HTTP HEAD request before getting the image. If this HEAD
request is unsuccessful Excel will return the exact error messages
mentioned in this discussion.

You can work around it by first downloading each image to a temp file, then inserting it from there.
Sub URLPictureInsert()
    Dim theShape As Shape, rng As Range, cell As Range, Filename As String
    Dim tempPath As String
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10")
    For Each cell In rng
        Filename = cell.Value
        If Len(Filename) < 5 Then GoTo skip
        
        'download the file to the temp folder and return the path
        tempPath = DownLoadedImagePath(Filename)
        
        Set theShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
            Filename:=tempPath, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
            Left:=cell.Left, Top:=cell.Top, Width:=60, Height:=60)
        
        Kill tempPath 'if removing downloaded files....

        With theShape
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Top = cell.Top + 1
            .Left = cell.Left + 1
            .Height = cell.Height - 2
            '.Width = cell.Width - 2
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        ' Get rid of the
        'cell.ClearContents
'isnill:
        'Set theShape = Nothing
        'Range("A2").Select

skip:
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Done " & Now

End Sub

'download content from `url` to a temp file and return the temp file path
Function DownLoadedImagePath(url As String) As String
    Dim Data() As Byte, tempPath As String, fNum As Long
    With CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        Data = .responseBody
    End With
    fNum = FreeFile
    tempPath = getTempPath()
    Open tempPath For Binary Access Write As #fNum
    Put #fNum, 1, Data
    Close #fNum
    DownLoadedImagePath = tempPath
End Function

'return a temporary file path
Function getTempPath() As String
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        getTempPath = .GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & .GetTempName
    End With
End Function


Depending on numbers, it might be wise to delete the downloaded temp file after successful insertion?

@CLR - yes might be a good idea if many images need to be fetched.

I use the =Image("cell with hyperlink", "cell with name of product', 0) function formula to grab pictures from a hyperlink on the product data i scrape off ebay, not sure if that will work for you or not but thought id throw it out there.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
